# SQL - Select all Entries where the difference between Characters at Position 10 and Position 20 Equals 1?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in a factory that manufactures electrical sensors.

We manufacture the Sensors in Batches (there's 10,000 Sensors in a Batch).
The Batches are referred to by Numbers like 1000**585855**; with the last 6 Digits being unique to each Batch.

The first stage of manufacturing the Sensor however (on a machine called Dispense), involves two Batches being processed together.

Generally, the Batches only differ by the last digit being +1 larger.
So for Batch 100058585**5**, the 'sister lot' will be 100058585**6**.
(When we reference these Lots being processed on Dispense in the Database, they are quoted as 1000585855_000585856.)

Occasionally however, the sister lot may be +2 or +3 larger (really it can be + any natural number).
So for example, I have seen 100045687**2**_000045687**4**.

The information relating to the batches is stored in an Oracle Database Table.
The Table is called the EM_EQUIPMENT_LG Table and is structured like so:

| EQUIPMENT_ID | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Dispense | 100073165**5**_00073165**6** |
| Dispense | 100074683**2**_00074683**3** |
| Dispense | 100073163**7**_00073163**9** |
| Dispense | 100057523**5**_00057523**6** |

Is it possible to construct a Query, whereby I obtain the BATCH_IDs, only where the difference between the 10th and 20th Characters (Bolded) is greater than 1?

So, if I was to utilise such a Query in the above example table, the only BATCH_ID returned should be 1000731637_9.  (As 9 minus 7 = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH            --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (EQUIPMENT_ID, BATCH_ID) AS
        (   
            Select 'Dispense', '1000731655_000731656' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Dispense', '1000746832_000746833' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Dispense', '1000731637_000731639' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Dispense', '1000575235_000575236' From Dual
        )
--  M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT  EQUIPMENT_ID, BATCH_ID
FROM    tbl
WHERE   To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 20, 1)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 10, 1)) > 1
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  EQUIPMENT_ID BATCH_ID            
--  ------------ --------------------
--  Dispense     1000731637_000731639
```

Maybe it would be better  to take two chars like  9th and 10th with 19th and 20th as there could be some problems with numbers ending with 0. Used To_number() because I dont like to be dependant on implicite conversions.

```sql
WHERE To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 19, 2)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 9, 2)) > 1
```

Comment: Hi, 

This worked perfectly whenever I used: 
`To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 20, 1)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 10, 1))`
Which is what I asked for, so many thanks! 

However, would I be pushing my luck to enquire about finding the difference between the Sister Batch ID's based on the last 6 Digits?
I tried using:
`To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6))`
but I receive an error message - ORA-01722 - Invalid Number

Comment: @JohnCampbell The invalid number error means that some of your data somewhere among the affected characters has a character that is not a number (couldn't be implicitly converted to a number). Did you try it with just 2 last numbers as sugested in the answer - that should solve it if both are realy numbers?

Comment: Thank you!
It turned out that I wasn't filtering the Batch ID column for just Numeric Values at those positions. I used a `WHERE` clause to fix this.

Final Question - Is it possible to also get a custom column in the results that shows the numeric difference between the Lot Values?

So for 1000585855_000585856, the Difference would be 1.
For 1000567894_000567897, the Difference would be 2. etc

So I'd get 3 Columns in the Results - EQUIPMENT_ID, BATCH_ID, DIFFERENCE.

Comment: I figured out how to create the custom column! ('Difference')

My only problem now, is that it is not ranking the data in numerical order.
Instead of ranking numbers in the order 1,2,3 etc. 
It is ranking them as 1, 10, 2 ,23 ,5 ,6 ,7 etc.

It Looks like the BATCH_ID Column is Type VARCHAR2

My current query is:

`SELECT  DISTINCT(BATCH_ID),To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6)) as Difference

FROM    POMSUSERPRD.EM_EQUIPMENT_LG
WHERE   To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6)) <> 1
AND UNIT_PROCEDURE_ID = 'Dispense'`

Comment: @JohnCampbell If you need the resulting dataset in any specific order you'll need the ORDER BY clause added to your query. Don't know where did 1, 10, 23, 5, 6, 7 come from but you need something like "  ORDER BY To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6))  " if the first part number is the ordering subject. Or maybe "  ORDER BY To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6))  " if  the added column DIFFERENCE is the one that you want to order by resulting dataset.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!
My current query is: (for anyone who is looking)
SELECT  DISTINCT(BATCH_ID),To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6)) as Difference
FROM    POMSUSERPRD.EM_EQUIPMENT_LG
WHERE   To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 15, 6)) - To_Number(SubStr(BATCH_ID, 5, 6)) <> 1
AND UNIT_PROCEDURE_ID = 'Dispense'
ORDER BY Difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR` to find the characters at those positions and then subtract (implicitly converting them to numbers):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ABS(SUBSTR(batch_id, 20, 1) - SUBSTR(batch_id, 10, 1)) > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (EQUIPMENT_ID, BATCH_ID) AS
SELECT 'Dispense', '1000731655_000731656' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dispense', '1000746832_000746833' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dispense', '1000731637_000731639' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dispense', '1000575235_000575236' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dispense', '1000575239_000575240' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EQUIPMENT_ID | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Dispense | 1000731637_000731639 |
| Dispense | 1000575239_000575240 |

---

Or, if you want to use all 6 digits then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ABS(SUBSTR(batch_id, 15, 6) - SUBSTR(batch_id, 5, 6)) > 1;
```

Which outputs:

| EQUIPMENT_ID | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Dispense | 1000731637_000731639 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HMRTi82_)

Answer (score 0):

In xase that the numabers are not fixed length you can try

```
CREATE TABLE batch
    ("EQUIPMENT_ID" varchar2(8), "BATCH_ID" varchar2(20))
;
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO batch ("EQUIPMENT_ID", "BATCH_ID")
         VALUES ('Dispense', '1000731655_000731656')
    INTO batch ("EQUIPMENT_ID", "BATCH_ID")
         VALUES ('Dispense', '1000746832_000746833')
    INTO batch ("EQUIPMENT_ID", "BATCH_ID")
         VALUES ('Dispense', '1000731637_000731639')
    INTO batch ("EQUIPMENT_ID", "BATCH_ID")
         VALUES ('Dispense', '1000575235_000575236')
SELECT * FROM dual
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM batch t
  WHERE To_Number(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(t."BATCH_ID", INSTR(t."BATCH_ID", '_')+1),-1)) 
   - To_Number(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(t."BATCH_ID", 1, INSTR(t."BATCH_ID", '_')-1),-1)) 
         > 1
```

| EQUIPMENT_ID | BATCH_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Dispense | 1000731637_000731639 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5a2xPBKD)

Comment: Would be better to take 2 chars for the case of BATCH_ID = '1000731637_000731640' .....

Comment: the user wanted only 1 but he can adept all the solutions easily